# How to increase the space between lines in Calibre reader?

Tags: ebook, calibre

I prefer the Calibre ebook reader to any other but I find one limitation: there is no obvious way (GUI) to change the space between lines.

I have found various solutions but these involved editing the ebook itself, or using CSS styles that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is no GUI option in settings for that in version 6.6.1.

The way to do it is to add a manual/text setting in Preferences - Styles, like this:

```
body 
{
   line-height:2.0em !important;
}
```

[image]

as said [here](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/13062026).

The important variable in the example here is the numeric part: `2.0`. `1.5` can be used etc.